# GUI does not seem to display when I create it in my main method

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I am having trouble getting my GUI to display, and I am certain I am missing something very simple. This is for homework. The class that contains the GUI is here :

```
public class SorcGUI extends JFrame{

    public void SorcGUI(){
        JTextArea jta = new JTextArea();
        JPanel jp1 = new JPanel();
        setTitle ("Sorcerers Cave");
        setSize (600, 600);
        setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JButton jbsearch = new JButton("Search");
        JTree jTree = null;
        JScrollPane treeView = new JScrollPane(jTree);

        JButton jbshow = new JButton("Show Contents");
        JButton jbread = new JButton("Import File");
        JScrollPane jsoutput = new JScrollPane(jta);
        JTextField jtfsearch = new JTextField("  enter search term  ");
        JLabel jlsearch = new JLabel("Search Type : ");
        JComboBox jcbsearch = new JComboBox <> ();
        jcbsearch.addItem ("index");
        jcbsearch.addItem ("Type");
        jcbsearch.addItem ("weight");

        //create a panel to hold the buttons and text fields

        jp1.add(jbread);     
        jp1.add(jbshow);  
        jp1.add(jtfsearch);
        jp1.add(jlsearch);
        jp1.add(jcbsearch);        
        jp1.add(jbsearch);
        jp1.add(treeView);


        //add the components to the GUI
        add(jp1, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        add(jsoutput, BorderLayout.CENTER);


        setVisible(true);

        jbread.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                SorcCave sc = new SorcCave();
            }
        });
        jbshow.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("show");
            }
        });        
        jbsearch.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("search");
            }
        });
```

And the way I am creating the GUI is simply adding the following to my main method:

```
SorcGUI gui = new SorcGUI();
```

The program simply goes form run to build successful in three seconds, never showing the GUI.  I am trying to clean up my projects by getting the GUI stuff into it's own class file.  Thank you for any help.

Comment: Show your main method please.

Comment: public static void main (String args []) {
         SorcGUI gui = new SorcGUI();
         //gui.setVisible(true);
      } // end main

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `void` keyword from the constructor of `SorcGUI` so the components can be added to the parent container

```
public SorcGUI() {
```

Read: [Providing Constructors for Your Classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html)

Comment: Remove `void` from method so it could become a `constructor`.

Answer (score 1):

I copy-pasted your code and commented the jbread action method and it works in a new Java Project in Eclipse IDE.

I only removed the 'void' from the constructor method.

[image]